# PhoneGap won't accept php scripts

Tags: php, cordova

I'm new to phoneGap and I just found out, It doesn't accept php scripts.

My problem is I have a php script that returns information from a database.

When I convert the .php script to a .html script(with embedded php), the information is not returned to the browser.

What can I do to fix this ?

Comment: tell your server to process .html files as php and rename your file to .html ?  have phonegap do an ajax request to the php file where the php file just returns raw html

Comment: Thanks, I prefer to do the "ajax request", Do you know any tutorial that illustrates a step by step process to do this

Comment: As stated by Jay in the phonegap faq they tell you how to do it using xmlhttpdrequest or using html5 based websockets

Answer (score 2):

According to the [PhoneGap FAQ](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/), you can't use PHP with it:

> **Q: Can you use PHP/ASP/JSF/Java/.NET with PhoneGap?**
>
> A: A PhoneGap application may only use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
>   However, you can make use of network protocols (XmlHTTPRequest, Web
>   Sockets, etc) to easily communicate with backend services written in
>   any language. This allows your PhoneGap app to remotely access
>   existing business processes while the device is connected to the
>   Internet.